# set up php-fpm for a centos 8 container

Tags: docker

```
FROM centos:8

RUN yum -y update && \
yum -y install  php-fpm httpd

COPY . /var/www/html

CMD ["httpd", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

I successfully created a simple container image based on centos:7 and it just works fine serving php files from document root. But, when I change the base to centos:8, php files are not served. The 503 Apache page is shown saying "The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later."
When I look into /etc/httpd/logs/error_log inside the running container, I see:

```
[Wed Jun 10 10:57:33.236099 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 7:tid 139731249620736] (2)No such file or directory: AH02454: FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /run/php-fpm/www.sock (*) failed
[Wed Jun 10 10:57:33.237322 2020] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7:tid 139731249620736] [client 172.17.0.1:46224] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: httpd-UDS
[Wed Jun 10 10:57:34.183056 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 7:tid 139731224442624] (2)No such file or directory: AH02454: FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /run/php-fpm/www.sock (*) failed
[Wed Jun 10 10:57:34.183132 2020] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7:tid 139731224442624] [client 172.17.0.1:46228] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: httpd-UDS
```

Tried to make a difference by creating /run/php-fpm directory inside the container for testing purposes, but the error still persists.

I really wish this would be solvable without `sed`ing something into php-fpm or httpd configuration files of the container.

Comment: Can you use the [Docker Hub `php` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/) variant with Apache installed instead; start your Dockerfile `FROM php:7.4-apache` before you `COPY` your application code in?

Comment: Tried that, but I get Syntax error on line 80 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: DefaultRuntimeDir must be a valid directory, absolute or relative to ServerRoot. Seems like I should pass in an ENV named APACHE_RUN_DIR. No matter what values I pass in it fails again.